# Babel error: Module build fails when I try to compile my front-end assets with Laravel Mix

Tags: vue.js, babeljs

I've been struggling with this error for a while and I went over different solutions on here as well as Git but just can't seem to get it working.

Error: `Module build failed: this.setDynamic is not a function`

These are the Babel dependencies I have in my package.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
  }
```

BeforeI was getting `Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3" #522` error and then I added `babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0`. My .babelrc file has:

```
{
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Could you please move your error to the question and add more descriptive title as well as error backtrace?

Answer (score 0):

After being stuck on this for almost 24 hours, I finally found the solution.

Just in case, if you happen to stumble across this due to having the same issue. Please check out [vuejs + babel-loader this.setDynamic is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52901717/vuejs-babel-loader-this-setdynamic-is-not-a-function). The issue is that the Babel documentation is not very clear. However, you issue should be solved if you follow the suggested answer accurately. Thanks.